# OpenSSL with unicode paths

Tags: security, unicode, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have an implementation of SSL handshake from the client side, by using these functions:
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file

All functions get char* type for the filename parameter.
How can I change it to support also unicode file locations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On which platform?  OpenSSL under Posix supports UTF-8 paths, but not on other platforms.  Chances are, you will have to manually load the certificate files yourself using standard OS file I/O functions that support Unicode paths, and then parse the raw data and load it into OpenSSL, such as via `PEM_read_bio_X509` with `sk_X509_NAME_push`, `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey/d2i_PrivateKey_bio` with `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey`, `d2i_X509_bio/PEM_read_bio_X509` with `SSL_CTX_use_certificate`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I need it to run on Windows...
What is the 'mapping' for SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no direct mapping.  You will have to hack it.  Internally SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() calls X509_STORE_load_locations(), which in turn calls X509_STORE_add_lookup(), X509_LOOKUP_load_file(), and X509_LOOKUP_add_dir().  Try defining a custom X509_LOOKUP_METHOD structure that opens a file any way you need, then pass that structure to X509_STORE_add_lookup() before calling X509_LOOKUP_load_file() and X509_LOOKUP_add_dir().  Since the API uses char*, you will have to use type-casting to pass a wchar_t* filename to your X509_LOOKUP_METHOD implementation.

Comment: Look in ssl_lib.c, x509_d2.c, x509_lu.c, and by_file.c to see how the current implementation of SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() is set up.  It's default X509_LOOKUP_METHOD used, SSL_LOOKUP_file(), uses the BIO API to read certificate files.  You will likely have to make your implementation also use BIOs, but you can use a BIO that is based on a FILE* so you can call _wfopen() to open Unicode filenames.

Comment: And what about SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file?

Comment: It sounds like you are not looking at the OpenSSL source code.  I strongly suggest you do.  These are not overly complicated functions to reproduce manually.

Answer (score 0):

I want to reply to the above post instead of creating a new answer, however I was not able to reply it, so I create a new answer. Based on my testing for SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations and looking at openssl code, actually the openssl would use utf-8 for file path as well on Windows. At the function BIO_new_file to open a file, it would choose utf-8 for file path if both _WIN32 and CP_UTF8 are defined. Those are defined at windows. However openssl also has code to fall back to ANSI path if path is not a valid utf-8 characters. So with that, actually openssl will work with both utf-8 and ANSI path on Windows.

Comment: I just found out that on windows the API SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file would require the ANSI path since it use a different function then BIO_new_file to read the file. The function is static long MS_CALLBACK file_ctrl(BIO *b, int cmd, long num, void *ptr) which doesn't have the utf8 to ANSI fall back.